# Run Binance Smart Chain Price Feeds from Chainlink on Testnet

Tags: testnets, chainlink, binance-smart-chain

I found the following link to get a price feed on Binance Smart Chain:
https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/link.html

However, I want to run it on a testnet first. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Data feed addresses for Binance Smart Chain testnet can be found in the [Chainlink Docs here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/binance-smart-chain-addresses/#BSC%20Testnet).

General instruction on how to use data feeds in a smart contract can be found in the [Chainlink Docs here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/).